# how to improve DPC Latency Checker times?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, latency

I'm using

HP DL360p Gen8, 2 * E5-2640 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

My friend is using

HP DL160 Gen8, 2 * E5-2640 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

We both made fresh Windows install, updated all drivers, used [this](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01804533/c01804533.pdf) guide for tuning.

So I expect that latency of my computer should be not worse (because dl360p is obviosly better than dl160)

However [this tool](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) shows that I have latency about 35-70 μs, but he has stable 10 μs.

Why do I have so worse latency and how can I know how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just because one number is higher doesn't automatically mean it's "Better" in all ways.

In this case, it's because the systems in question are aimed at different workloads,

From HP's site:

HP DL360P:

> "***this server is ideal for general purpose applications***, such as,
>   file/print or web, as well as, dynamic computing workloads,
>   virtualization and cloud solutions."

HP DL160:

> "a high performance, low cost, ultra-dense rack ***server designed for
>   memory intensive High Performance Computing*** (HPC) environments, web
>   serving ***and memory intensive applications***."

Why they act different technically is going to be *all the other parts* in the system that aren't the CPU and OS.

Motherboards, chipsets, etc. play a HUGE role in how fast a computer really is, especially when narrowing in on one or two specific metrics.

Comment: it's very interesting to know what exact part (what chipset or controller) of DL160 is better comparing to DL360? because DL160 is much cheaper!

Comment: also DL160 Gen9 supports maximum E6-2660, more powerfull processors can not be used. DL360 supports all processors. hp itself recomends using powerfull processors like 2687W http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01804533.pdf